# How can I add "related" tag/keyword to search from start menu for an UWP app

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app, keyword-search, windows-search

To search a windows app from start menu search or windows search we type the display name of an app. However, I wanted to add customized keyword/tags to search my UWP app from that search. For some searches we see windows app suggestions or related app. For example if we search *Browser* in the search *Microsoft Edge* shows up.

[image]

More examples can be like : if we type *mail* in the search *Outlook* app shows up, if we type *uninstall* then *Add or remove program* shows up.

I wanted to know how can I add that feature to my app that If I search a certain tag/keyword in the search box my app shows up i.e. if I search "myapp" then "ExampleUWPApp" shows up.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I add "related" tag/keyword to search from start menu for an UWP app

I have to say there is not such entry to add tag for your app, the only thing could be build as search tag is package display name. And system searching tag is build internally base on Bing search engine. And this is a good suggestion that add searching tag for apps. I'd suggest you submit a feedback/feature request about this API/feature in the Feedback Hub.